# Edit the code of module in venv during docker build in Django + React app

Tags: python, django, docker

I have React as frontend and Django with Django REST Framework working as API. And the issue is I changed several lines of code in module I installed for Django app. Obviously, during Docker build those changes aren't saved. Because .venv folder for virtual environment isn't copied to container. I'm asking a way to make changes to module in `.venv` folder during build. The number of changes isn't huge. Only two lines.

The module is `django-rest-multiple-models==2.1.3`(https://pypi.org/project/django-rest-multiple-models/)

In `drf_multiple_model` folder which is I believe a main folder of the module in `.venv` I changed following(lines 196-207):

```
    def get_label(self, queryset, query_data):
        """
        Gets option label for each datum. Can be used for type identification
        of individual serialized objects
        """
        if query_data.get('label', False):
            return query_data['label']
        elif self.add_model_type:
            try:
                return queryset.model._meta.verbose_name
            except AttributeError:
                return query_data['queryset'].model._meta.verbose_name
```

There was `__name__` instead of `verbose_name`

Dockerfile in Django app:

```
FROM python:3.10-alpine
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
WORKDIR /server
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

services:
  backend:
    build:
      context: ./server
    command: gunicorn core.wsgi --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    expose:
      - 8000
    depends_on:
      - postgres
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is much simpler than it looked for me at first. Use OOP:

1. Inherit required module's class.
2. Override the required method.
3. Use the overridden class.